# Run this line by line, or as a whole

Tags: windows-7, command-line, flask

I am trying to install flask. [Docs say](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/installation/#create-an-environment) to make an environment:

> Create an environment
>
> Create a project folder and a venv folder within:
>
> Windows
>
> ```
> mkdir myproject
> cd myproject
> py -3 -m venv venv
> ```

How should I run those?

- one line at a moment and the other?
- all in a one or write a *`bash`-y* script?

I am on `cmd.exe`, Windows 7.

Comment: One line at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I run these?

Each line is a separate command in `cmd`, so they should be run one at a time:

1. `mkdir myproject`
2. `cd myproject`
3. `py -3 -m venv venv`

Note that line 3 assumes you have installed [`py` launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) (e.g. as part of the installation process with ["vanilla" Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)) and that it is available from the command line (checked via `where py` in `cmd`). Regarding the command itself:

- The `-3` portion specifies the use of whatever default version of Python 3 `py` launcher is aware of.
- `-m venv` invokes the native Python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (virtual environment) module.
- The final `venv` is the "name" (path) of the virtual environment created (i.e. what the folder created holding the necessary `venv` files will be called).

Be aware that any virtual environment will need to be "activated" in each new `cmd` window you open, if you intend to use it (i.e. use the modules you install in them, including flask). That is, you will need to run some version of:

```
C:\path\to\venv\scripts\activate.bat
```

each time you wish to use `flask` in a new `cmd` window.

Personally, I have a preference  for creating batch file "aliases" with just the appropriate line e.g.:

*ex. py_flask.bat*

```
C:\path\to\venv\scripts\activate.bat
```

and placing those files (`py_flask.bat`) in a folder available in my Windows System Path environment variables. This allows the use of just e.g. `py_flask` from any open `cmd` window to activate the associated environment and avoid typing a (likely) longer full path.

Comment: The activation step was the next step :). Check the link.

Comment: I appreciate the check. But you can certainly accept Gantendo's answer if you ever change your mind. He certainly answered first. =)

Answer (score 2):

You should run the commands one line at a time.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy Accept Anaksunaman's answer, He has cool quotes on his profile.

Comment: *"He has cool quotes in his profile"* - Lol! Thank you both! ;)